# CakePHP 3 - Two foreach loops and associated models

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach, cakephp-3.0

The database contains the following tables: `posts`, `posts_authors` and `users`.

- `posts table fields`: *id*, *name*, *slug*, *content*, *created*, *modified*, *user_id* (record creator, not author), and *online*.
- `posts_authors table fields`: *id*, *post_id* and *user_id*.
- `users table fields`: *id*, *name*, *slug*, *email*, *password*, *country_id*, *avatar*, *created*, *modified*, and *status*.

I'm trying to list all posts and all the authors for each post, but I don't know how to get the name of the users from their IDs in the second foreach loop.

**CODE :**

**My View**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    ...

    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($post->authors as $authors): ?>
        <li><?= $authors->users[0]->name ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    ...

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**PostsAuthorsTable.php (Model)**

```
...

$this->belongsTo('Users');
$this->belongsTo('Posts');

...
```

**PostsTable.php (Model)**

```
...

$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'through' => 'PostsAuthors',
]);

...
```

**UsersTable.php (Model)**

```
...

$this->belongsToMany('Posts', [
    'through' => 'PostsAuthors',
]);

...
```

**PostsController.php (Controller)**

```
public function index()
{   
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Posts.online !=' => -1]
    ])->order(['Posts.publication' => 'DESC'])->contain(['Users']);

    $this->set(compact(['posts']));
}
```

Comment: well, firts: how you get your `$posts` array in your controller? Then if Post belogsToMany users should be `$post->user` instead of `$post->author`

Comment: @arilia Thanks for commenting! Just added `PostsController.php` to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    ...

    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($post->users as $user): ?>
        <li><?= $user->name ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    ...

<?php endforeach; ?>
```